# How to calculate the cooling timescale of a giant planet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation, planets, cooling

I have the following  question from my Astronomy class.

> Show that the cooling timescale of a giant planet scales linearly with
>   radius. Assume that its thermal energy content is proportional to its
>   volume and that its cooling rate is proportional to planet surface
>   area.

A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html#c2

Comment: With all due respect but which eggs cools down faster: a quail's egg or a dinosaur egg? Rara!

Comment: @Gert. Due respect etc, it has  been 65 million years since well, nobody tasted a Dino egg..... although if you have a minute, you might be interested in this off topic item  http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-36737185

Comment: @CountTo10: it'll make America great again!

Comment: If it takes 6 hours to thaw a turkey, how long to thaw a wooly mammoth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate at which a planet cools will in part be determined by the ratio of its surface area to its volume. 
For a spherical planet of radius $r$, the volume is $\frac {4}{3}\pi r^3$ and the surface area is $4\pi r^2$.

Now get the ratio of these two quantities, which will demonstrate that  a larger planet will cool more slowly than a smaller one.

So pick two planets from the solar system and see how it works out.

Enough nudges.

Best of luck with it.

Comment: Newton;s law of cooling treats *convective cooling*, that's not applicable in space.

Comment: @Gert whoops, deleted from post thanks, a planet is not a dead body, even Mars. Too much CSI, sorry.